# Trying to prove $f(x)- P_{n-1}(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^n-1}{n-1} f^n(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am trying to prove $f(x)- P_{n-1}(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^n-1}{n-1} f^n(t) dt$.

I can't get off the ground with the integration, however. We just cover Darboux integrable functions, but I think this is only related to our study of the Taylor Series.

I know I eventually need to get something like

$f(x) = P_n(x) + \frac{f^k(c)}{k!} (x-c)^k$

but I can't make the algebra come out right

1. starting with $P_{n-1}(x)$ on the LHS 
   and
2. assuming the RHS after integrating is $\frac{f^{n-1}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n$.

That was my hunch, but I'm fairly certain this an incorrect evaluation.

Also, how to justify pulling $f^k(c)$ out of the difference? MVT?

Any help understand how to attack the integral appreciated.

Comment: What is $P_n (t) $?

Comment: I assume he means $P_{n-1}(x)$ is the $(n-1)^{st}$ degree Taylor polynomial approximation of $f$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
f(x)-f(x_{0})&=\int_{x_{0}}^{x}f'(t)dt\\
&=(t-x)f'(t)\bigg|_{t=x_{0}}^{t=x}-\int_{x_{0}}^{x}(t-x)f''(t)dt\\
&=(x-x_{0})f'(x_{0})+\int_{x_{0}}^{x}(x-t)f''(t)dt\\
&=(x-x_{0})f'(x_{0})-\frac{1}{2}(x-t)^{2}\bigg|_{t=x_{0}}^{t=x}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}(x-t)^{2}f^{(3)}(t)dt\\
&=(x-x_{0})f'(x_{0})+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_{0})^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}(x-t)^{2}f^{(3)}(t)dt,
\end{align*}
by induction, 
\begin{align*}
f(x)=f(x_{0})+(x-x_{0})f'(x_{0})+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}(x-x_{0})^{n}+\frac{1}{n!}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}(x-t)^{n}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt.
\end{align*}